# Big picture of domain, mobile app website and server

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, hosting

I am new to backend world, currently I am very confused with these concept relationships and really need some help here.
So currently I already have an iOS app and backend server(using python, hosting at AWS) ready. Now I need to register a new domain name and build a basic website to explain and promote my app.
Let's assume I am using goDaddy to register a domain name as "hello.com", now I have my basic website ready as well, I guess I need to upload html files to goDaddy hosting server then the website should be able to run, but then how can I link it to our python server? 
For example, in the iOS code when I am sending a http request, I will need to send it to "https://hello.com/api/xxx", correct? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use subdomains for the different servers:

- www.hello.com = your static website hosted on Godaddy or wherever
- api.hello.com = your Python api server

etc...

To make this work you would just edit your DNS zone on Godaddy (or wherever you have your domain hosted) and create a record for "www" that points to your website server and a record for "api" that points to your API server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, do we have any way to hide "api.hello.com"? because I don't want user know our api is under this domain...

Comment: Not really. Maybe you should just stick to an elastic IP if you don't want the domain associated with the api.